# save error when function is not present in controller in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling, runtime-error

I want to get error in a variable when I call a function in **cakePHP** controller. If function is not present then i should get error in my variable. I have called function in another controller like:

```
App::import('Controller', EventsController);
$EventController = new EventsController;    
$postData = $EventController->dataToBeSend();
```

Here I want, **$postData**  should contain following error if function is not present

> Call to undefined function dataToBeSend()

---

how could i achieve this?

Comment: Use function_exists() to check if your function is loaded or not

Comment: can u write its one line syntax or any link regarding to it?

Comment: Source http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

Comment: You shouldn't really be importing a Controller into another Controller in CakePHP. If there is shared functionality either put it in `AppController` or write a Component and use it on the required controllers.

Comment: `$postData = $EventController->dataToBeSend();` are you _really_ only trying to get `$this->data` ? Don't create controller instances like shown in the question, it's never the right solution.

Comment: ok I am getting what should i do. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

you should use function_exists() function. It gives you Boolean value in return to represent either the function has been loaded or not.

Comment: While valid, this answer doesn't address that the code in the question is the wrong way to do .. well anything.